# CALayer: Screen point to Layer point

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

I have a `CGPoint` which is in screen coordinates.
I also have a `CALayer` with applied transform matrix (scale, rotation and translation).

How can I transform the point which is in screen's coordinates into layer's local coordinates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CALayer` has method to do this, look for `– convertPoint:fromLayer:` and `– convertPoint:toLayer:` in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html)